# no puedo evitar mostrar una peticion en electron

Tags: nodejs, electron

tengo un problema con una petición http en electron; estoy intentando hacer una simple solicitud http al hacer click en un botón y luego mostrar el resultado en consola y en un text area, pero antes de ejecutarse la sentencia la validación para mostrar info en consola muestra la respuesta cuando es error 400

```
const send_post = async (url) => {
        try {
            let res = await fetch(url, { method: 'POST' }) //aqui imprime cuando es error #1
            if(res.ok){
              console.log(res.ok)
            }/*else{
              console.log(res.status) //aqui vuelve a imprimir el error #2
             }  
             */
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
}
```

asi yo no le indique que imprima, se imprime el error y cuando es error 400 imprime 2 veces el error, mi pregunta es como puedo hacer para que solo imprima el error en la condicional indicada

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quiero obtener algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]